# knockoutjs select data-bind binding is given unexpected result

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am just started to use knockoutjs. I try to bind the select option value with knockout data-bind property.But am not able to get the array values as different options.
It will populate as coma separetd.
i had attaching the sample code i tryied.I hope some others will also face the same strange error.

```
self.availableStates = new Array(); 
for (var i=0;i<self.allStates.length;i++)
{
if (self.allStates[i]['name'] != null)
self.availableStates.push(self.allStates[i]['name'])
}
self.availableStates = ko.observableArray([self.availableStates]);
```

**Expecting result:**

```
<select id="drpDwnLst" data-bind="options: availableStates">
    <option value="">State4</option>
    <option value="">State3</option>
    <option value="">State2</option>
    <option value="">State1</option>
</select>
```

**Actual result**

```
<select id="drpDwnLst" data-bind="options: availableStates">
    <option value="">State4,State3,State2,State1</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see in the output is the effect of calling `toString()` on an array.

You get this result because your  `availableStates` **is already an array** so you don't need to wrap it again to an array with `[]`

So you need to just write:

```
self.availableStates = ko.observableArray(self.availableStates);
```

Although it is strange how you override your `self.availableStates` definition...

Comment: Thank you it's working now...What is your second point i didn't get you..?

Comment: In your sample you definied `self.availableStates = new Array();` then you override it with `self.availableStates = ko.observableArray(self.availableStates);`. The `observableArray` also implements most of the array functions so you write e.g `self.availableStates = new observableArray(); self.availableStates.push("State1");`